# Merge/Dissolve features by attribute which touches each other, but with an exception

Tags: qgis

I am searching for an option to merge or dissolve a lot of features, which share the same attribute (shown as the colour of the lines in the attached images) and touches each other [image: overview]
[image: legend]

I tried to use dissolve by attribute and multipart to singlepart afterwards. The challenge is, there has to be an exception: I only want to merge continuous lines, even if there are side branches with the same attribute:

[image]

This is for a big set of features so doing it per hand is no option, does anyone has an idea?

[Sample Dataset](https://we.tl/t-6YZXr5J9Hs)

Comment: `Dissolve` first, then running `multi-to-singlepart` is not option?

Comment: You can also try the ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) algorithm with an expression, that includes `overlay_touches(@layer)`

Comment: but this should include sidebranches as well because they also touch... right? I only want to merge the main branch parts together

Comment: Does no one have an idea?

Comment: How do you define a side branch? It is easy to understand in a drawing but how do you get the computer to understand... The longer (not side) lines, are they always split where the side branches are / are they always not split / can it vary? Can you share the data?

Comment: I do not know how to define the side branch thats the problem... I attached a sample dataset for you

Comment: I would start by
1. dissolve by attribute
2. split with lines & extract the start and end vertices (0, -1) of the lines (you don't need the split anymore), which yields you the points where lines branch off
3. check if lines with the same attribute intersect (field calculator in the point layer)
4. split at those points
5. dissolve by $length, assuming your main line is longer than the side branches